# Triggers combined to work dynamically in oracle apex application

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I need to create dynamic approval workflow in apex application so i have created triggers for that.
However i need to combine these/make the logic dynamic.

Trigger 1 sends email to first approver for approval.
When the approver logs in to approve, set p_it_issues.APPROVE_THIS='Y', the next trigger sets p_it_issues.approved=1 to show it has passed first level. 
The second trigger sends email notification to second approver as well. (all code mentioned below for reference).
However in this app, the approval levels should be dynamic, for one dept there could be 2 approvers and for another there could be 3.
My logic as of now is, say HR dept has 2 levels of approval. 
So after second approval when p_it_issues.approved =2 and it matches p_it_departments.approval_level( the number of approvals department wise) set as =2, the issue can be resolved. (This last condition, i can still put as authorization scheme to set issue as resolved only when the 2 match).

But due to varying levels of approval this would means i will have to create more and more triggers.
Is there a way to combine this so that it would keep incrementing and sending approvals from p_it_people.approver='Approver 1'.to..'Ápprover n' based on approval_level per department? HR has 2, so it would noly send it to the 2 approvers in p_it_people table with Approver column set as Approver 1 and 2 respectively?

For more clarity my 2 triggers and subsequent table structures are present.

Let me know if any more clarification is required.
I understand this seems long and tedious but any help would be much much appreciated.

Trigger 1 for first level approval:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  P_IT_ISSUES_AIU_Notify_Approver_1
AFTER 
insert on P_IT_ISSUES 
for each row 
FOLLOWS P_IT_ISSUES_AIU_EMAIL
declare
v_person_id number;
v_email varchar2(255);
v_dept_name varchar2(50);
begin
select p.person_id ,p.person_email,i.dept_name into v_person_id,v_email,v_Dept_name from p_it_people p,p_it_departments i 
where p.assigned_dept=i.dept_id and i.dept_id=:new.related_dept_id and p.approver='Approver 1'  ;

             APEX_MAIL.SEND( 
                 p_to => v_email, 
                 p_from => v_email, 
                 p_body =>  
                 'You have been assigned a new issue for first level approval.  ' ||chr(10)|| 
                 'The details are below. ' ||chr(10)|| 
                 chr(10)|| 
                 ' Department:'|| v_dept_name ||chr(10)|| 
                 ' Summary: '||:new.issue_summary ||chr(10)|| 
                 ' Status: '||:new.status ||chr(10)|| 
                 'Priority: '||nvl(:new.priority,'-'), 
                  p_subj => 'New Issue for First Level Approval'); 


end;

/
```

Trigger 2, to set p_it_issues.approved=1 when p_it_issues.approve_this='Y' by first approver.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  P_IT_ISSUES_AIU_Notify_Approver_2
BEFORE 
update on P_IT_ISSUES
for each row 
declare
v_person_id number;
v_email varchar2(255);
v_dept_name varchar2(50);

begin

if :new.APPROVE_THIS = 'Y'
 then :new.APPROVED :=1 ;
 end if;

select p.person_id ,p.person_email,i.dept_name into v_person_id,v_email,v_Dept_name from p_it_people p,p_it_departments i 
where p.assigned_dept=i.dept_id and i.dept_id=:new.related_dept_id and p.approver='Approver 2'  ;

             APEX_MAIL.SEND( 
                 p_to => v_email, 
                 p_from => v_email, 
                 p_body =>  
                 'You have been assigned a new issue for second level approval.  ' ||chr(10)|| 
                 'The details are below. ' ||chr(10)|| 
                 chr(10)|| 
                 ' Department:'|| v_dept_name ||chr(10)|| 
                 ' Summary: '||:new.issue_summary ||chr(10)|| 
                 ' Status: '||:new.status ||chr(10)|| 
                 'Priority: '||nvl(:new.priority,'-'), 
                  p_subj => 'New Issue for Second Level Approval'); 


end;
```

Table structures:
People:

```
CREATE TABLE  "P_IT_PEOPLE" 
   (    "PERSON_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PERSON_NAME" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PERSON_EMAIL" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PERSON_ROLE" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ASSIGNED_DEPT" NUMBER, 
    "CREATED_ON" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MODIFIED_ON" DATE, 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "PERSON_PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "APPROVER" VARCHAR2(50), 
     CONSTRAINT "P_IT_PEOPLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PERSON_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "P_IT_PEOPLE_NAME_UK" UNIQUE ("PERSON_NAME")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "P_IT_PEOPLE_USERNAME_UK" UNIQUE ("USERNAME")
    ALTER TABLE  "P_IT_PEOPLE" ADD CONSTRAINT "P_IT_PEOPLE_DEPT_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ASSIGNED_DEPT")
          REFERENCES  "P_IT_DEPARTMENTS" ("DEPT_ID") ENABLE
```

Departments:

```
CREATE TABLE  "P_IT_DEPARTMENTS" 
   (    "DEPT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DEPT_NAME" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "APPROVAL_LEVEL" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "P_IT_DEPARTMENTS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DEPT_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
/
```

Issues:

```
CREATE TABLE  "P_IT_ISSUES" 
   (    "ISSUE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ISSUE_SUMMARY" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ISSUE_DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "IDENTIFIED_BY_PERSON_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "IDENTIFIED_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "RELATED_DEPT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ASSIGNED_TO_PERSON_ID" NUMBER, 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PRIORITY" VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TARGET_RESOLUTION_DATE" DATE, 
    "PROGRESS" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "ACTUAL_RESOLUTION_DATE" DATE, 
    "RESOLUTION_SUMMARY" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "CREATED_ON" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MODIFIED_ON" DATE, 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "APPROVED" NUMBER, 
    "APPROVE_THIS" CHAR(1), 
     CONSTRAINT "P_IT_ISSUES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ISSUE_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "P_IT_ISSUES_PRIORITY_CC" CHECK (priority in ('High','Medium','Low')) ENABLE
   )
/
ALTER TABLE  "P_IT_ISSUES" ADD CONSTRAINT "P_IT_ISSUES_ASSIGNED_TO_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ASSIGNED_TO_PERSON_ID")
      REFERENCES  "IT_PEOPLE" ("PERSON_ID") ENABLE
/
ALTER TABLE  P_IT_ISSUES ADD CONSTRAINT "P_IT_ISSUES_IDENTIFIED_BY_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("IDENTIFIED_BY_PERSON_ID")
      REFERENCES  "P_IT_PEOPLE" ("PERSON_ID") ENABLE
/
ALTER TABLE  P_IT_ISSUES ADD CONSTRAINT P_IT_ISSUES_PROJECT_FK FOREIGN KEY (RELATED_DEPT_ID)
      REFERENCES  P_IT_DEPARTMENTS (DEPT_ID) ENABLE
/
```

Basically looping in trigger shooting mails from approver 1...approver n whee n is number of approvals application per department in departments table.

Answer (score 0):

Vini,
Trying to have multiple triggers on the issues table I believe would be problematic and very rigid. Instead I would create additional tables to drive the approval process.

APPROVAL_LEVEL in P_IT_DEPARTMENTS I assume holds the number of levels of approvals required (1,2,3, ...).

I would create an intersection table between P_IT_PEOPLE and P_IT_DEPARTMENTS, called P_IT_DEPT_APPROVERS which holds FKs plus APPROVER_LEVEL type NUMBER. This table allows any person to be assigned as an approver for a given department with a specified approval level.
If the APPROVER_LEVEL (from intersection table) greater than APPROVAL_LEVEL (from departments) then error.

I would create another table as an intersection table between P_IT_ISSUES and P_IT_DEPT_APPROVERS, called P_IT_APPROVALS, which records which user has approved and when.

In P_IT_ISSUES I would include APPROVAL_LEVEL (NUMBER) to record the current approval level, APPROVAL_COMPLETE_YN VARCHAR2(1) to indicate it has been approved.

An after insert trigger on P_IT_APPROVALS can count if all approvers for a specific level have approved the issue and in that case, update the P_IT_ISSUES table with the new approval level and if not more approval levels set approval complete, otherwise, send to the next level approvers.

Regards,
David

Comment: Hi David, This last point about creating the trigger. How can this be made dynamic to send email from one approver to another? When Approvers 1 approves then email is triggered to the next and so on..

Comment: I would do the following
1. get current Approval Level from IT Issues
2. Count total people in IT_Dept_Approvers (How many approvers needed)
3. count total approvers for the issue in IT_Approvers (How many approved)
4. If 3= 2 then check if next level approvers exist in IT_Dept_Approvers
  - If Yes  set IT_Issues Approval_Issues to current + 1 and send emails to all those in next approval bucket from IT_Dept_Approvers
  - If No set IT_Issues Approval_Complete to Yes

Comment: Hi Davif, How will "If the APPROVER_LEVEL (from intersection table) greater than APPROVAL_LEVEL (from departments) then error." get implemented? I have per department approval levels, say Finance has approval level 2. In the intersection i would have 2 rows for 2 approvers. So how and where will i put this condition to match the two? Secondly Instead of table will a view be fine?